# Como renombrar texto con JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero remplazar ciertos caracteres y no se como hacerlo automaticamente con 
Tampermonkey. Lo ideal es hacerlo con `jquery`

El `HTML`:

```
<div class="panel-body" data-loading-overlay="" style="">
<table id="list-files" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="35">
<div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
<input type="checkbox" id="select-all-files" checked="">
<label for="select-all-files"></label>
</div>
</th>
<th>File</th>
<th>Size</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr><td><div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input name="files[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="0"><label></label></div></td><td class="pt-none pb-none"><div><div class="pull-left mt-xs mr-xs">*NOEDITABLE*Rambo-First.Blood.1982.Multi.2160p.UHD Bluray.x265.HDR.DTS.5.1-DTOne / </div><div style="overflow:hidden"><input class="form-control input-sm m-none" style="background-color: transparent" type="text" name="rename[0]" value="Rambo-First Blood (1982) Multi 2160p UHD Bluray x265 HDR DTS 5.1-DTOne.mkv"></div></div></td><td>14.5 GiB</td></tr><tr><td><div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input name="files[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="1"><label></label></div></td><td class="pt-none pb-none"><div><div class="pull-left mt-xs mr-xs">*NOEDITABLE*Rambo-First.Blood.1982.Multi.2160p.UHD Bluray.x265.HDR.DTS.5.1-DTOne / </div><div style="overflow:hidden"><input class="form-control input-sm m-none" style="background-color: transparent" type="text" name="rename[1]" value="A DT0ne Release !!!.txt"></div></div></td><td>287.0 iB</td></tr><tr><td><div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input name="files[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="2"><label></label></div></td><td class="pt-none pb-none"><div><div class="pull-left mt-xs mr-xs">*NOEDITABLE*Rambo-First.Blood.1982.Multi.2160p.UHD Bluray.x265.HDR.DTS.5.1-DTOne / </div><div style="overflow:hidden"><input class="form-control input-sm m-none" style="background-color: transparent" type="text" name="rename[2]" value="File downloaded from TheSite.tv.txt"></div></div></td><td>28.0 iB</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
<div class="loading-overlay" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;"><div class="bounce-loader"><div class="bounce1"></div><div class="bounce2"></div><div class="bounce3"></div></div></div></div>
```

Acá lo que intento hacer es que se reemplacen algunos caracteres pero solo los que correspondan a los box editables, no lo que sería el `HTML` sino lo que uno puede manipular, ej concreto:

**SIN EDITAR:**
    value="Rambo-First Blood (1982) Multi 2160p UHD Bluray x265 HDR DTS 5.1-DTOne.mkv"

**EDITADO:**

```
value="Rambo-First.Blood.1982.ENg-Multi.2160p.Bluray.x265.HDR.DTS.5.1-DTOne.mkv"
```

Osea el `script` solo debería manipular los box editables..

Mi ´script´:

```
$(function(){
  var label_text = $('#list-files').text();

  $('#list-files').text( label_text.replace("(Multi)", "(ENg-Multi)") );
})
//También reemplazaría los espacios por puntos, quitaría los parentesis, etc.
```

Desde ya que está mal y rompe todo, es evidente que tiene que ser más específico y es ahí donde no puedo encontrarle la vuelta.

***Espero su ayuda y no importa otros métodos de lograrlo siempre que sean con JQuery***

Answer (score 1):

**puedes hacerlo utilizando una expresion regular:**

```js
// remplazo 

function strRemove(str){
 return str.replace(/[\. ,():-]+/g, ".");
}

var str="Rambo-First Blood (1982) Multi 2160p UHD Bluray x265 HDR DTS 5.1-DTOne.mkv";
alert(strRemove(str));
```

Comment: Como podría aplicarlo al Tampermonkey sin que me salga la alerta y edite solo el texto?

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo en dos pasos también:

> obtener el texto del objeto `$('selector').val()` y eso asignarselo a una variable, Luego a esa variable le aplicas un regex.

```
var str = "Visit Microsoft!";
var res = str.replace(/microsoft/i, "W3Schools");
```

Comment: soy demasiado iniciado en esto, no se como aplicar ese código al Tampermonkey, gracias

Comment: con tamperMonkey es lo mismo, solo que debes definir de donde y a donde vas a cambiar el texto